# Converting from Swift "data" to double precision floating point

Tags: swift

I have the following 3 lines of code:

```
self.latitude = data[0...7].withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
self.longitude = data[8...15].withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
self.altitude = data[16...19].withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
```

The first two (latitude and longitude) are sent as 8 byte double precision floating point numbers (float64_t) from a C++ program on a separate computer (BeagleBone).

The altitude (float32_t) converts perfectly, but the two doubles do not.  What else do I need to do to retrieve the doubles from the data stream?

Comment: What is the contents of `data`, what results do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: The struct transmitted is the following:  struct DataPacket {
    float64_t latitude;
    float64_t longitude;
    float32_t altitude;
    float32_t velocity_u;
    float32_t velocity_v;
    float32_t velocity_w;
    float32_t acceleration_u;
    float32_t acceleration_v;
    float32_t acceleration_w;
    float32_t pitch;
    float32_t roll;
    float32_t yaw;
    float32_t ch4;
    float32_t ethane;
} ;   <br>. I get values for the latitude and longitude - they are just smaller numbers than I expect (e.g. 0.8 instead of 40)

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, not to the comments. What is the *concrete* contents of data? – `print(data as NSData)`

Comment: Oops, it was idiotic - sorry...  The conversion was working - they were just specified in radians when I expected degrees....  Thanks for looking!